# GitLab CI running for file changes in directories not included in `rules: changes`

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have the following rules for a CI job that runs testing.

```yaml
  rules:
    - changes:
        paths:
        - "__tests__/*.js"
        - "jest.config.js"
        - "src/FileCabinet/SuiteScripts/**/*.{js|json}"
```

However when I make a commit on the same branch to change `README.md` the job runs as well. It is not a new branch which I understand it will run for because there is no previous SHA hash for the branch.